Prime gap modulo n
There are multiple questions on the prime gap https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap in here.
I tried to find if the gap pattern can be used to differentiate integers somehow.
Here is my attempt to generalize the prime gaps:

For a given integer number $n > 1$ find all primes $p_i$ such that $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$
Obviously, all the gaps between $p_i$ are multiples of $n$, so we calculate the gaps as $g_i = \frac{p_i - p_{i-1}}{m}$,
where $m = n$ if $n$ is even, and $m = 2n$ if $n$ is odd; $p_0 = 1$

Let us denote the distribution of gaps calculated this way for a number $n$ as $G(n)$.
Using a Python program I calculated the distributions on a set of primes less than $1000000000$ ($50847534$ primes ending on $999999937$) for a number of positive integers.
Here are some observations on the generalized gaps:

Number $2$ acts as it was an infinite odd prime:
the larger a prime number $p$, the closer $G(p)$ to $G(2)$;
the most contrasting prime is $3$





Multiplying on $2$ or any power of $2$ does not change the distribution: $G(2^kn) \sim G(n)$





$G(n) \sim G(rad(n))$, where $rad(n)$ is the radical of $n$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer


Does it make sense, or it is a statistical or some other kind of error?
Is there a mathematical justification of the observations?
Unfortunately, the statistics is not enough for reliable statements on $n > 1000$.
